# iterating through a large 20+ gb file from a server with python

Tags: python, paramiko, linux-mint

Hi I have about 16 20+ gb files on a server that I need to read specific entries from, I have the code working that reads the file in the correct order if I have one of the files saved on my computer

```
f = open('biodayk1.H2009', 'rb')

lbl = array.array('f')

bio = 0 for day in range(iday):
    f.seek(nx*ny*km*bio*4, 1)
    lbl.read(f, nx*ny*km)    #reads the desired ibio
    f.seek(nx*ny*km*(10 - bio)*4, 1) #skips the next ibios 
f.close()
```

Now I need to read the files from the server without downloading each file. I was looking into paramiko and was able to connect to the server but I'm not quite sure how to iterate through a file and just return what I want. If you need any more info or need me to answer any questions please ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're... in for pain. I recommend you follow the rsync route and write a script that runs on the server which serves up the bytes you're interested in. You can communicate with it via a text channel created by paramiko.

Comment: Even deleting files over the wire takes an order of magnitude longer than just telling the machine to delete it's own files. You wouldn't think so, but...

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I'll look into it. Thanks. (I'd vote you up but my reputation is too low)

Comment: You can try and set up a cherrypy server and use some simple get params

Comment: If I was going to go HTTP then I'd go the whole way and support ranges.

Comment: I should probably mention that I'm a complete beginner haha. So if I throw my program on the server then do something like:
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python reader.py')

Comment: It's something like that, except you run your remote script instead. Just send the desired ranges through `stdin`, and read them out through `stdout`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. How much data can I send through stdout? Will I be able to send like 2gb? or does it need to be broken up?

Comment: There's no built-in limit, but the more you send, the longer it will take.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `execnet` to run a bit of Python (a local function or module) remotely.

No setup required.

Comment: You still need a Python installed on server, though. But it looks good.